# Can I use iptables to forward between interfaces without setting /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward?

Tags: iptables, forwarding

Can I use iptables to forward between interfaces without setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`?

I want a secure default of not forwarding anything and then specifying exactly what should be forwarded.

Comment: Why not instead a default `:FORWARD DROP [0:0]` in iptables and then setup whatever allow rules are necessary?